# Strange exception handling practice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, exception

I have seen code like this (actually seeing another person type it up):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exception = ex.ToString();
}
```

Is this code bad? If so, why? There is an appropriate "chain of catch handlers (eg more specific one above, filtering down to general catch all Exception, but in the string conversion of the Exception, I guess you are converting a lot more than is probably needed, to a string (All you really need is the InnerMessage or one of the other string properties depending on the scenario). Any thing else wrong with this code?

I have also seen devs put breakpoints on every line of code. What is the point of this? Why not just put one at the top and then use "run to cursor" (love that feature)?

Finally, what's the advantage of using break on all exceptions in Visual Studio?

Comment: I think your snippet is a very good example of a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This developer might not know that you can catch all (managed) exceptions like this ...

```
try
{
  // do something
}
catch( Exception )
{

}
```

And not suffer the compiler warning of a catch block like this ...

```
catch( Exception ex )
{
  // don't use ex
}
```

Also, he might not know about the [$exception pseudo-register](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/09/22/did-you-know-you-can-add-exception-to-the-watch-window-to-see-the-caught-exception-318.aspx).

Comment: Actually, you only need `catch {}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
   string exception = ex.ToString();
```

That doesn't DO anything.  Better to log it or use MessageBox.Show(...);.

Breakpoints on each line ... not much point - use run to cursor or step over/step in.

Break on all exceptions: I've actually used.  I've had exceptions fail quietly that were "handled" by some library silently.  Break on all helped me track that down.  Additionally "Break on all" can help you make sure you're only getting exceptions you expect (Also helped by not catching a generic "Exception" class but only catching the particular exception.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I suspect this line would even get optimised out by the compiler in Release mode.

Comment: Additionally I think Visual Studio will give a warning stating you've got a string that is assigned to but never used.

Comment: Not if he cleverly added #pragma warning disable 0169 ;)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a lazy programmer who:

1. Doesn't want to handle exceptions properly
2. Wants a spot to set a breakpoint if there's an exception.

Comment: Alternatively, there may be a policy of no empty `catch` blocks, perhaps enforced via some automated tool - and this code is written solely to circumvent that.

Comment: Nope, there are no policies or automated rule enforcing.

Answer (score 2):

The only value of the code you posted would be to permit the full exception to be visible while in the debugger. It's not *necessary*, since the debugger will do that anyway, but maybe this code was there since before the debugger did that.

Comment: I've seen this exact code as it gets written in the last few weeks lol (Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition/.NET 2.0/3.5).

Answer (score 0):

I just used "break on all exceptions" yesterday.

I was chasing down a pretty obscure bug (in fact, the code was working perfectly, which is the hardest kind of bug of all to find), and while my C# code was executing an apparently-malfunctioning IronPython script, I kept getting `ArgumentException` messages appearing in the console.

It turns out that this IronPython code:

```
try:
    value += x
except ValueError:
    pass
```

results in an `ArgumentException` being thrown, and handled, inside the IronPython runtime.

Also, if you have "break on all exceptions" turned on, VS actually breaks on that `value += x` line, calls up the Python source, lets you inspect local values, etc.  Pretty nice.  Anyway, now when I see those exception messages show up in the console I no longer worry that I'm ignoring something that's going to bite me.